# terraform-compliance steps not distinguishing resources in plan

Tags: terraform, bdd, terraform-template-file

I would like to use `terraform-compliance` to prevent users from creating a `aws_s3_bucket_policy` to attach policies to `aws_s3_bucket` resources and instead, I would like for them to use the `aws_iam_policy_document` data object.

The bucket is created using a module and the module appends the JSON from `aws_iam_policy_document` to the bucket's policy. I have tried all manner of step statement combinations in my feature file, but terraform compliance seems unable to distinguish between `aws_iam_policy_document` explicitly declared and the `aws_iam_policy_document` which is an attribute of the created bucket.

Here's what I want:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "some_custom_policy" {
  foo = bar
}

module "my_s3_bucket" {
  ...
  policies = [
  {
    policy_name = "Policy name"
    policy_json = data.aws_iam_policy_document.some_custom_policy.json

  }]
}
```

What I want to fail:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "some_custom_policy" {
  bucket = module.my_s3_bucket.output_bucket_name
}

module "my_s3_bucket" {
  ...
}
```

This feature passes for both cases:

```
Feature: Force proper S3 bucket policy use
    Scenario: aws_s3_bucket_policy is used instead of aws_iam_policy_document for S3 buckets
        Given I have aws_s3_bucket_policy resource defined
        Then it fails
```

Removing the word `resource` from the Given step fails for both cases thus:

`Forcefully failing the scenario on aws_s3_bucket_policy (module.my_s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3_policy) resource`

How do I get terraform-compliance to properly filter out `aws_s3_bucket_policy` and only allow `aws_iam_policy_document`?

P.S.: I know that this is not really a terraform question, but I do not have enough rep to create a new `terraform-compliance` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to reproduced your scenario, but couldn't. Is it possible to post a `plan.out.json` (if its not confidential) as an issue on github.com/terraform-compliance/cli please ?

Here was my test tf ;

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test" {
    bucket = "test-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "fail" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test.id
    policy = ""
}
```

and here is my feature ;

```
Feature: test
    Scenario: aws_s3_bucket_policy is used instead of aws_iam_policy_document for S3 buckets
        Given I have aws_s3_bucket_policy defined
        Then it fails
```

this is the output I got ;

```
Feature: test  

    Scenario: aws_s3_bucket_policy is used instead of aws_iam_policy_document for S3 buckets
        Given I have aws_s3_bucket_policy defined
        Failure: Forcefully failing the scenario on aws_s3_bucket_policy (aws_s3_bucket_policy.fail) resource
        Then it fails
       

1 features (0 passed, 1 failed)
1 scenarios (0 passed, 1 failed)
2 steps (1 passed, 1 failed)
```